# Криво работает code runner в vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не работает нормально.
после запуска в консоли в google chrome, code runner делает эту часть нормально, но пока не запустишь все остальное в браузере так же не выдает результат. node js установлен

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: 1. Судя по белой точке, файл не сохранен - потому и не виден нужный результат. 2. Не выкладывайте код картинками.